# Can ssh internally, but can't externally: port 22: connection refused

Tags: networking, ssh

I'm trying to connect to the my Raspberry Pi over SSH.

I'm able to do it internally (`ssh user@raspberrypi`), but when I try to connect externally (over public IP) it says:

> port 22: Connection refused

I set up port forwarding in the router and disabled the firewall, but still get the same problem. What other causes can there be?

Comment: you likely didn't set up port forwarding correctly, or for some reason your ISP blocks port 22.   I usually do port translation with port forward, i.e. External IP:port 42020 -> Internal IP:port 22.   Then SSH user@externalIP:42020

Comment: Use the port scanner [here](https://www.grc.com/x/ne.dll?rh1dkyd2) to see if your port is open from the outside.

Comment: Well bad link... Grc.com and the port scanner is the shields up tool

Comment: I checked using that tool and it says that 22 and 80 are both open.

Comment: I also double checked my port forwarding and it appears to be correct. I tried to redirect ports, but still no success.

Comment: Can it be the case that because I'm trying to access from within the same network, it clashes somehow?

Comment: Yes!  You must test port forwarding from outside.  Some routers will "hairpin", but you can't assume that it will.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33598/discussion-between-rizhiy-and-tyson).

Comment: @Rizhiy Does your ISP provide a public IP ? If that's not that case, you won't be able to connect it directly. How to check ? Refer this answer : http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/11411/how-can-i-tell-if-my-isp-is-employing-nat

Comment: @dastaan I have set up a no-ip service and can view my website using it, so I assumed I can also ssh using the same address.

Comment: @Rizhiy: In that case, you can rule out my comment. There must be some `forwarding misconfiguration` at play. As answer below suggested, you can try using different external port number (possibly above 1024) and forward it to internal pi ip : port 22 using custom TCP forwarding.

Answer (score 1):

Below are the most common reasons that users seem to have trouble with an ssh connection.

1. **You haven't enabled forwarding or have enabled it incorrectly**

If you don't enable port forwarding from the router, or have configured it incorrectly, the connection will be refused. Instructions on this will vary based on the router, but ensure that the forwarded IP address is the same that the RPi is using.

Also, note that the address can change from time to time. I have my router set to always give my RPi the same address because of this.

2. **Your ISP may disable traffic on port 22**

I have never experienced this personally, but some networks block "common home server ports", such as 21 and 22.  If they do, there's nothing you can do to enable those ports. Switching to a different port will usually solve this problem, even if it is a bit annoying.

3. **You're trying to connect from the same network**

Some routers don't like it when the destination is within the same network.  The Motorola I previously rented from Comcast would fail with the same error, but my TP-link manages the connection without an issue.

Comment: I don't get it.  I enabled port forwarding on my Google OnHub router.  I registered a subdomain with Google Domains.  I set up ddns daemon on my Pi.  Why isn't it working?